# Erro ao enviar arquivos por Java Socket

Tags: java, socket

Servidor.java

```
   package javaapplication48;

   import java.net.*;
   import java.io.*;

   public class Servidor {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(5656);

         Socket sv = servidor.accept();

         ObjectInputStream out = new ObjectInputStream(sv.getInputStream());

         FileOutputStream file = new 
   FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\DeveloperEng\\Documents\\newOrder.xml");

         byte[] buf = new byte[4096];

         while (true) {
            int len = out.read(buf);
            if (len == -1) break;
            file.write(buf, 0 , len);
         }
     }   
  }
```

---

Cliente.java

```
  package javaapplication48;

  import java.net.*;
  import java.io.*;

  public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5656);

        ObjectOutputStream out = new 
  ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());

        FileInputStream file = new 
  FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\DeveloperEng\\Documents\\order.xml");

        byte[] buf = new byte [4096];

        while (true) {
           int len = file.read(buf);
           if (len == -1) break;
           out.write(buf, 0, len);
       }
   }   
}
```

---

No NetBeans, eu executo primeiro o Servidor.java e depois o Cliente.java. Mas ele gera o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in
>   use: JVM_Bind     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)  at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)     at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:128)   at
>   javaapplication48.Servidor.main(Servidor.java:9)
>   C:\Users\DeveloperEng\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>
> Java returned: 1 FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)

Se alguém souber dizer porque ele gera essa falha e, se possível, me ajudar a corrigir código, eu seria muito grato!!

Answer (score 2):

Existe algum processo na sua máquina escutando na porta `5656`. Considerando que você está utilizando Windows:

```
netstat -ano | find "5656"
```

lista o processo escutando na porta `5656`. Em seguida, utilize

```
taskkill -pid "pid do processo" /f
```

para matar o processo escutando na porta `5656`.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela ajuda, mas continua gerando o erro. Eu matei o processo na porta e até tentei usar outras portas, mesmo assim ele mantem dando erro. Teria alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: @AndréSpironello mesmo utilizando outras portas gerou o mesmo erro? Tem certeza que você está parando a execução do projeto quando ele lança o erro antes de rodá-lo novamente?

Comment: sim, eu parei a execução sempre que ia tentar novamente. Tentei até reiniciar o computador, mesmo assim ele continuava gerando o mesmo erro

Comment: consegui resolver o problema. Quando eu criava a conexão entre o servidor e o cliente, o programa do cliente ficava travado quando tentava ler o que o servidor estava mandando pela porta, porque o servidor não estava mandando nada! Como eu não havia implantando nem o método para fechar a conexão do cliente, nem uma exceção para tratar isso, a conexão na porta continuava aberta mesmo que eu encerrasse o servidor. Com as modificações que eu fiz, o cliente lê o que o servidor manda, imprime o resultado e fecha na sequência. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!